# how to write in excel cells using DataReader if a particular cell is "ReadOnly" using C#

Tags: c#, .net, readonly, export-to-excel

I am using DataReader to write data into excelsheet cells. I have no problem until the cell has write previleges. But in one case, only one cell is readonly and the rest cells are writable.

Eg : 10 * 10 cells, only first cell is readonly. so, i shuld leave this cell and write it to rest of the cells. But with the data reader it writes entire row at one go.. so how can i acheive this using C# ?

```
Team Leader (required) , , , , , , , , , 
, , , , , , , , , ,
, , , , , , , , , ,
, , , , , , , , , ,
, , , , , , , , , ,
```

so, the first cell shouldn't be written by datareader. 
Please help me in doing this

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    minRow = 0;
    minCol = 0;
    // Process each result in the result set
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Create an array big enough to hold the column values
        object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        // Add the array to the ArrayList
        rowList.Add(values);
        // Get the column values into the array
        reader.GetValues(values);
        int iValueIndex = 0;

        // If the Reading Format is by ColumnByColumn 
        if (CurTaskNode.ReadFormat == "ColumnbyColumn")
        {
            minCol = 0;
            //   minRow = 0;
            for (int iCol = 0; iCol < CurTaskNode.HeaderData.Length; iCol++)
            {
                // Checking whether the Header data exists or not
                if (CurTaskNode.HeaderData[minCol] != "")
                {
                    // Assigning the Value from reader to the particular cell in excel sheet                   
                    excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol] = values[iValueIndex];
                    iValueIndex++;
                }
                minCol++;
            }
            minRow++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Ramm

Answer (score 1):

Found this on google so maybe it works/maybe it doesn't:
[here, code looks the same as yours](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10111727/condition-to-check-whethe.aspx)

You can use the AllowEdit property of a range so you could do:

```
// Assigning the Value from reader to the particular cell in excel sheet      
Excel.Range c = (Excel.Range)excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol];
if (c.AllowEdit) c.Value2 = values[iValueIndex];
```

instead of

```
// Assigning the Value from reader to the particular cell in excel sheet                   
excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol] = values[iValueIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot to figure out how to skip writin onto a particular excel cell using C#, but couldnt get the proper logic.

my eg:
*Team Leader (required) abcxyz  User1   user2
Customer Interface Focal    dfgidf  user23  user3*

each of the names above has to be in a particular cell... but in the excel template, first cell (Team Leader (required)) is readonly, so i cant write into that cell, so my final excel sheet should show

```
                            abcxyz  User1   user2
Customer Interface Focal    dfgidf  user23  user3.....
.....
```

i tried various logics for this... please see the code below

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook SelWorkBook = excelappln1.Workbooks.Open(
    curfile,
    0, false, 5, "", "", false,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
    "", true,
    false, 0, false, false, false);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets excelSheets = SelWorkBook.Worksheets;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelworksheet =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(CurSheetName);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelworksheet.UsedRange;

if ((!excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol]).Locked)
{
    // Assigning the Value from reader to the particular cell in excel sheet 
    excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL +      minCol] = values[iValueIndex];
    iValueIndex++;
}
```

but the error shows, in the if statement
Error   1   Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'object'

so, please say how to handle this case.

Thanks
Ramm